# Countable Intersection of Sets of Second Category

Tags: general-topology, analysis, baire-category

We say a set is of *first category* if it is a union of countably many nowhere dense subsets.

If a set is not of first category, we say it is of *second category*.

Now I am thinking of a question.

Suppose for each $t\in [0,1]$, we have a set $A_t$ which is dense and of second category in $[0, 2\pi]$, which is our background complete metric space.

Let $C$ be an countable subset of $[0,1]$.

---

My question is:

Is $\cap_{t\in C}A_t \neq \emptyset$ for any $A_t, C$?

---

I know a set of second category is "relatively large" roughly speaking, but I don't have a precise characterization/picture of it in my mind. What sets of second category look like? If with the picture, it may be easier for me to think of the question above. Thanks for any help either with the question or with this picture problem.

Comment: Why would the intersection be empty? Take every set $A_t$ to be equal $[0, 2\pi]$

Comment: @Jakobian Sorry, maybe I should put the question in this way: Is $\cap_{t\in C}A_t \neq \emptyset$ where $A_t,\forall t\in[0,1],$ is dense and of second category in $[0,2\pi]$, and $C$ is a countable set subset of $[0,1]$?

Comment: $$A_t-[(0,\pi)\cap\mathbb Q]\cup[(\pi,2\pi)\setminus\mathbb Q]\text{ if }t=1$$ $$A_t=[(0,\pi)\setminus\mathbb Q]\cup[\pi,2\pi]\cap\mathbb Q]\text{ if }t\neq1$$ $$C=\{1,\frac12,\frac13,\dots\}$$

Comment: @bof Thanks for the counterexample. Can you further tell me that what sets of second category look like? Any "pictures" are also ok. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

Even the intersection of two sets of the second category (also called *nonmeager sets*) can be empty.

For example, in the space $X=[0,\pi]$, both $[0,1]$ and $[2,3]$ are of the second category for example by the Baire category theorem, being complete metric spaces.  But their intersection is empty.

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meagre_set for more examples involving these concepts.